How to convert Spectral Response curves of different units into each other?
I am now building a little database of several monochromatic cameras (and their mono CMOS sensors), now trying to gather data in unified units from several sensor manufacturers. However, I have run into difficulties recently.
The spectral response of a sensor is indicated very differently throughout different manufacturer websites and datasheets. Take the following examples:
Example A: This is from the datasheet for a camera that uses a Sony IMX 253, and its spectral response graph has a Y axis labeled as "Relative Response", where curve values range from 0.0 to 1.0: (Original source: https://docs.baslerweb.com/aca4112-30um#spectral-response ; last accessed 2024.11.02. 09:26 CET)

Example B: The following is from the datasheet for the ams CMV 2000 sensor, here they label the Y axis as "Quantum Efficiency (%)", and curve values range from 0 to 65: (Original source: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/588/AMSY_S_A0004028489_1-2573336.pdf ; last accessed 2024.11.02. 09:26 CET)

Example C: The following is from the datasheet for the ams CMV 4000 sensor, here they label the Y axis as "Spectral response [A/W]", and curve values range from 0.0 to 0.25: (Original source: https://eu.mouser.com/pdfDocs/CMV4000_DS000728_3-00.pdf ; last accessed 2024.11.02. 09:28 CET)

Example D: The following is from the datasheet for the e2v EV76C570 sensor, here they label the Y axis as "LSB/nJ/cm2", and curve values range from 0 to 24: (Original source: https://www.1stvision.com/cameras/sensor_specs/DSC_EV76C570.pdf ; last accessed 2024.11.02. 09:28 CET)

Example E: The following is from the online data page for the Gpixel GMAX 0505 sensor, label the Y axis as "QE x FF (%)", and curve values range from 0.0 to 70.0: (Original source: https://www.gpixel.com/en/pro_details_11126.html ; last accessed 2024.11.02. 09:29 CET)

The question: How to convert any other of the mentioned curves into a QE(λ) curve? (As the QE curve is supposeldy the most widely understood/used curve of all the mentioned.)
Plus, I would be grateful if you could in your answer kindly elaborate on the following aspects: Which of the mentioned Y axis units are bare substituents of each other? Which of the mentioned Y axis units could be directly converted to one another, using general physics principles or non-sensor-specific constants? Which of the mentioned Y axis units are convertible to each other, given another sensor-specific characteristic or mesured contant blended into a conversion equation?
Thank you for any help!

Disclaimer: I am hobbyist who knows some physics and have been reading some technical literature from time to time.

Quantum efficiency: linear scale, probability of photon causing electron to add to pixel well (capacitor) when it hits the pixel detector.
Relative sensitivity: proportional to QE but normalized so that maximum = 1 (i.e. relative to peak sensitivity).
Example C: the A/W is pixel well current per incident light power (Amperes per Watt) and is not fully proportional to QE because photon energy is proportional to it's wavelength. Ampere is unit of current (amount of electrons crossing a boundary) and is proportional to number of electrons.
Example D: LSB is in the glossary there as "Least significant bit" and refers to ADC output, not pixel well. The graph is proportional to A/W graph. Iso-QE lines are for informative purpose and illustrate what I said about Ex. C.
Example E: QE*FF is proportional to QE since FF = fill factor and is constant. Since sensor is not 100% covered by detectors' active surface QE might be measured for individual pixels or for sensor on average. QE*FF means explicitly that fill factor is included in QE.

So, to your questions:

If your aim is to know the colour reproduction characteristics then all units can be converted according to what I've said, no additional information is needed.




Relative efficiency cannot be converted to QE without knowing QE at least for one wavelength.
Whether QE includes fill factor or not should be deduced from the document.
LSB per power is fundamentally different from A/W because it very likely refers to ADC output, not pixel wells. But iso-QE lines are giving you the conversion ratio anyway (it seems to that they correspond to some specific ISO sensitivity which is characteristic of ADC).


Relative sensitivity is the largest common denominator of all those graphs. If you want to gather just the colour reproduction properties that's totally enough. So, in general, A/W must be corrected using wavelength and then it becomes fully proportional to QE and other units are proportional to either of those two.


Thank you, this already clarifies many things! Although I was asked by the forum to edit my question, which I did recently. So feel free to leave the answer as it is, or change it if you wish. I am just waiting now for other possible answers too
